# Kali Linux on WSL 2 times out when attempting to upgrade

Tags: linux, kali-linux

Kali Linux on WSL 2 times out when attempting to upgrade

I'm trying to install Kali Linux so I can do Hack the Box challenges from my laptop.

I'm following Kali Linux install and setup guide from [NetworkChuck](https://youtu.be/AfVH54edAHU?t=161) on YouTube.

I've got the Kali Linux app installed and running on WSL 2.

When I attempted to update Kali, I get a timeout error message. Why is it so?

```
┌──(me!!!!㉿DESKTOP-LHRQ2R4)-[/etc/apt]
└─$ sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
Ign:1 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease
Ign:1 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease
Ign:1 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease
Err:1 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease
  Could not connect to http.kali.org:80 (192.99.200.113), connection timed out
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling/InRelease  Could not connect to http.kali.org:80 (192.99.200.113), connection timed out
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

What I have tried

1. https://forums.kali.org/ - which hasn't seemed to be up today...
2. I've plugged diectly into my home router using a network cable
3. I've tried hotspotting through my mobile phone
4. I can browse to http://http.kali.org/kali which takes me to the page headed "Index of /kali"
5. I've confirmed the InRelease file it's looking for is in the directory I think the update is looking at - *http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling/*
6. Rolling back to WSL 1 and trying it
7. uninstallilng, reinstalling Kali via Microsoft app store
8. various laptop restarts
9. my /etc/apt/sourcelist file looks like this

> deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib

Comment: The Kali forum is absolutely working, if it’s not working, that means your dns is incorrect or something is blocking it

Comment: In the first lines of the error (your post) you are not connected to the Internet. Solve that first, as I do not think this is an update issue. Make sure Internet is working in the Kali machine. Same setup here: Kali is updating fine.

Comment: WSL is just a way to run Linux commands from within Windows. If may be worth your while to to uninstall WSL, restart, install it again and then load a new instance of Kali and see if it connects to the internet.